# Get percent volume

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate, pavucontrol, amixer

I am trying to show the percent of my sound volume on my desktop.

Using amixer get Master

```
amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Master',0
```

pavucontrol works, but it causes the light for my webcam to be always on.

Any other way?

Comment: @Mordoc Got page not found.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Ubuntu_Mate 18.04 LTS

#
echo "Sound Volume is " >>  %Volume.txt
amixer -c 1 -M -D pulse get Master | grep -m 1 -o -E [[:digit:]]+% | tr -d "%" >> %Volume.txt
echo "%" >> %Volume.txt
gxmessage -fg red -font 'sans 20' -timeout 3 -file %Volume.txt -geometry "600x200"
rm %Volume.txt
```